# NIO - Can state of readiness of channel be lost?

Tags: java, nio

I am new to a non-blocking IO in Java. I have a question - will a readiness of a non-blocking channel be lost by the selector, if a new packet from a server will arrive after we completed reading from the channel, but before we removed a selection key for this channel from selector? Example code here:

```
        Selector selector;

        // ......

        while (true) {
            selector.select();
            Set<SelectionKey> set = selector.selectedKeys();

            Iterator<SelectionKey> iterator = set.iterator();
            while (iterator.hasNext()) {
                SelectionKey key = iterator.next();
                SocketChannel channel = (SocketChannel) key.channel();
                ByteBuffer byteBuffer = ByteBuffer.allocate(GOOD_ENOUGH_CAPACITY);
                while (channel.read(byteBuffer) > 0) ;

                // HERE ! What happen if server started to write new message here?
                // Will this channel be selected on next selector.select() ?

                iterator.remove();

            }
        }
```

Comment: the keys are "validated" during select. it doesn't matter when you call it, if the channel is readable/writable (and depending on the interestedOps) it will be selected. If there is unread data it will be readable. If you do not remove it from the selected set it will obviously stay there. On a side note: using NIO w/ non-direct buffers is sorta waste. On the contrary SSLEngine shall not be used w/ direct buffers since the internal impl. relies on byte[]

Comment: @bestsss +1 except for the part about non-direct buffers. They are only useful if you have no need to get the data into the JVM itself, such as when just copying data. If you're writing requests or responses in an application protocol, direct buffers are contra-indicated.

Comment: @EJP, you can still use direct buffers for protocols, you can even wrap something like DataOutputStream into a buffer. Yet my main gripe is the Java (Sun's impl) of byte[] backed ones. byte[] has to be copied at some point to a direct buffer. Java allocates them and keeps a 'small' cache into a thread local. Attempting to write long messages (bigger than the socket buffers) results into an allocation of a pretty big direct buffer. Then the entire byte[] is copied into the the direct buffer. Since the socket buffer can't hold it, the leftover is discarded and the process repeated. Overhead...

Comment: @bestsss Of course you can use them, but there is no benefit in doing so, quite possibly the reverse.

Comment: @EJP, my experience w/ direct buffers is quite positive. I'd go that far to say if you design the application to take benefit of them (and not mindlessly copying 'em around) it'd outperform any non-direct buffer approach. Alas, SSL impl. frowns them, so it's not trivial to say: direct buffers always win.

Comment: @EJP, i didn't even think of plain copy. Although there is no trouble to analyze a BufferBuffer just as byte[] req/resp is the least network dependent type of activity, the heavy load is usually forming the response. Still can use a ByteBuffer for, though. Mass subscribe->send is usually where direct buffers shine since they don't need to copy the content (heap ones do).

Comment: @bestsss Of course, but most applications don't just copy data from one channel to another. There is no benefit to using direct buffers in a request/response protocol where you have to analyse the request and compute the response, rather than just getting it all from another channel. If the data has to cross the JNI boundary there is no benefit in using a direct buffer as opposed to a normal ByteBuffer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, key will be selected. You must use method

```
key.cancel();
```

to remove key from selector

Comment: Or close the channel. Many people do both, which is witless.